# Determine name of file with Pandas to csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv

So I have a script capable of finding the z-score for different dataframe.

I'd like my script to save my files (if I'm applying it to multiple dataframe) under specific name depending on name of the dataframe I'm applying the script to.

Here's my dataframe:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]})
```

And this is the code I'm using:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from statistics import mean
import csv

class stats:
    def __init__(self, df):
        self.df = df
        self.min = self.get_min()
        self.pos = self.get_pos()
        self.log = self.get_log()
        self.z = self.get_z()
        #self.mean = self.get_mean()

    def get_min(self):
        get_min = abs(np.amin(self.df))
        return get_min

    def get_pos(self):
        get_pos = self.df + self.get_min() + 1
        return get_pos

    def get_log(self):
        get_log = np.log2(self.get_pos())
        return get_log

    def get_z(self):
        z_score = []
        get_z = (self.get_log() - np.mean(self.get_log()))/np.std(self.get_log(), ddof=1)
        z_score.append(get_z)
        return get_z

    def save_z(self):
        self.get_z().to_csv("z_" + str(z_data) + ".csv")


data = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]})
data_list = list(data.columns)
z_data = stats(df=(data[data_list]))

#print(z_data.get_min())
#print(z_data.get_pos())
#print(z_data.get_log())
#print(z_data.get_z())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    z_data.save_z()
```

The part I'm trying to fix is this one:

```
def save_z(self):
        self.get_z().to_csv("z_" + str(data) + ".csv")
```

I'd like my file to have the name "z_data.csv" (if the dataframe name was x the name would than be "z_x.csv).

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the name of the variable? For various complicated reasons related to the python object model, you cannot* do that (* easiliy, or without catches).

Much clearer and more reliable to to just pass a string to your class:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from statistics import mean
import csv

class stats:
    def __init__(self, df, label):
        self.df = df
        self.label = label
        self.min = self.get_min()
        self.pos = self.get_pos()
        self.log = self.get_log()
        self.z = self.get_z()
        #self.mean = self.get_mean()

    def get_min(self):
        get_min = abs(np.amin(self.df))
        return get_min

    def get_pos(self):
        get_pos = self.df + self.get_min() + 1
        return get_pos

    def get_log(self):
        get_log = np.log2(self.get_pos())
        return get_log

    def get_z(self):
        z_score = []
        get_z = (self.get_log() - np.mean(self.get_log()))/np.std(self.get_log(), ddof=1)
        z_score.append(get_z)
        return get_z

    def save_z(self):
        self.get_z().to_csv("z_" + self.label + ".csv")


data = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]})
data_list = list(data.columns)
z_data = stats(df=data[data_list], label='z')

#print(z_data.get_min())
#print(z_data.get_pos())
#print(z_data.get_log())
#print(z_data.get_z())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    z_data.save_z()
```